# The ideal wood for the DIY slate?

Tags: diy

I am planning to create a DIY [slate/clapperboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard). What would be the ideal wood for the clapper? I believe that the main qualities of the ideal wood would include, but not limited to, the following:

- Toughness : the ability to withstand lots and lots of clapping.
- Sound : it should make the snappiest and loudest sound compared to other woods; although, I am not sure whether there is a major difference among the types of woods.
- Budget : Of course, we should always try to keep our costs as low as possible.

What type of wood I should be looking for?

Comment: Larch, naturally. (-:

Comment: @JimMack Really? Why would you say that? I thought that hardwoods would be more preferable than softwoods, such as Larch.

Comment: sorry, it's a Monty Python reference. If I had an actual response I would have made it an answer, not a comment.

Comment: What about a tablet? Less romantic, but there are slate apps that do the job, and you can see them in the dark. Just for my information, what are you shooting on? Unless you're shooting film, then even if you're recording on a separate audio device you can use the on-camera sound as a synch track and automagically synch with software such as FCPX, Premiere or Pluraeyes. 

Otherwise, a good dense hardwood should be fine. The old wood slates I've used were plywood, with a hardwood strip along the jaws.

Comment: I would consider acrylic instead of wood... It is just me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure there is an ideal wood.  In fact, it really doesn't even need to be wood.

The entire point of a clapper is simply to make an audible sound that comes from an easily visible source.

As long as the sound is loud, short and crisp you are fine.  If you wanted, you could have your three year old be the clapper instead and just give him two pots to bang together.

The convention of a clapper is simply because it is a convenient device that also allows for indicating other meta data about the shot.  The clapper part is just included so that you can also capture the audio sync data without needing another device.

Comment: agreed here but if you still want to make one, I would use a hardwood for the clapper bit and a bit of plywood for the face. Otherwise you could use some PVC strips which would be longer lasting

Comment: Otherwise they are not that expensive to buy when if your interetsed, eBay have some decent ones http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Mini-Acrylic-Clapboard-Dry-Erase-Director-Film-Movie-Clapper-Board-Slate-UK-BL-/291307821448?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item43d34c9988 I bought one of them for abotu £20 I think, saved me time and effort trying to make one, but its up to you if your still set on making one